# Rest API with JSON using Integration

Tags: apex, api, integration, json, rest

I have created 3 classes.

1. APex Class
2. Callout Class
3. JSON Parser Class

In that "apex class" I'm calling the JSON class. It shows the error"Invalid type: templateAttributes1" Line number 29. Please find the below code.

Apex Class:

```
global with sharing class Deliquientdays {
    global List<loan__Loan_Account__c> Deliquientdaynotice(){
        set<id> Deliquient75;
        set<id> Deliquient87;
        set<id> Deliquient108;

        String templateId1 = 'Template87';
        String templateId2 = 'Template108';
        String endpoint = 'http://172.31.77.142:8080/de-service/api/trigger/email';
//        Deliquientdaycallout da = new Deliquientdaycallout();
//        da.doPostMethod('endPoint');
        List<loan__Loan_Account__c> llaList = [select loan__Contact__r.name,loan__Contact__r.Email,name, loan__Number_of_Days_Overdue__c,                                       loan__Oldest_Due_Date__c,loan__Loan_Status__c  
                                               from loan__Loan_Account__c 
                                               where loan__Number_of_Days_Overdue__c in (75,87,108) 
                                               AND loan__Loan_Status__c = 'Active - Bad Standing'];
        for(loan__Loan_Account__c lla: llaList){
//          if(lla.loan__Number_of_Days_Overdue__c == 75 || lla.loan__Number_of_Days_Overdue__c == 87 || lla.loan__Number_of_Days_Overdue__c == 108){
                if(lla.loan__Number_of_Days_Overdue__c == 75){
                    String templateId = 'Template75';
                    String Promocode = 'TESTPROMO123';
                    String FName = lla.loan__Contact__r.FirstName;
                    String LName = lla.loan__Contact__r.LastName;
                    String Email = lla.loan__Contact__r.Email;
                    String contactid = lla.loan__Contact__c;
                    String HomeURL = 'http://172.31.77.142:8080/de-service/api/trigger/email';
                    /* etTemplateBody parent = new etTemplateBody(lla.loan__Contact__r.Email, templateId, lla.loan__Contact__c);
                    parent.tas.add(new templateAttributes1(FName, LName, HomeURL, Promocode));*/
                    etTemplateBody parent = new etTemplateBody(Email, templateId,contactid );
                    parent.tas.add(new templateAttributes1(FName, LName, HomeURL, Promocode));
                  }
                }
                String jsonPayload = JSON.serialize(parent);

              Deliquientdaycallout da = new Deliquientdaycallout();
              da.doPostMethod(endpoint, jsonPayload);

/*                 if(lla.loan__Number_of_Days_Overdue__c == 87){
                    Deliquient87.add(lla.Id);
                }
                if(lla.loan__Number_of_Days_Overdue__c == 108){
                    Deliquient108.add(lla.Id);
                }
 */                                       
//            }
        }
    }
```

JSON Wrapper Class:

```
public class etTemplateBody {
    public String toAddress, templateId, contactId;
    public templateAttributes1[] tas;
    public etTemplateBody(String toAddress, String templateId, String contactId) {
        this.toAddress = toAddress;
        this.templateId = templateId;
        this.contactId = contactId;
        tas = new templateAttributes1[0];
    }
    public class templateAttributes1 {
    //For APPROVED_NEED_TO_ESIGN_WITH_PROMOCOD
        public String FirstName, LastName, HomeURL, Promocode;
        public templateAttributes1(String FirstName, String LastName, String HomeURL, String Promocode) {
            this.FirstName = FirstName;
            this.LastName = LastName;
            this.HomeURL = HomeURL;
            this.Promocode = Promocode;
        }

     }
}
```

Callout Class:

```
global with sharing class Deliquientdaycallout {
   global void doPostMethod(String endPoint, String jsonBody) {

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();
        System.debug('****Trying to reach the URL:' + endPoint);
        req.setHeader('Authorization','Basic VEVTVEVSOlRFU1RFUg==');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        req.setEndpoint(endPoint);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        System.debug(jsonBody);
        req.setBody(jsonBody);
        try
        {
           res = http.send(req);
           if(res.getStatusCode()==200)
           {         
           System.debug(res.getStatusCode());
           System.debug(res.getStatus());
           }
       }
       catch(System.CalloutException e) 
       {
            System.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
            System.debug(res.toString());
        }
   }
}
```

Please help me resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the outer (containing) class needs to be used too:

```
parent.tas.add(new etTemplateBody.templateAttributes1(FName, LName, HomeURL, Promocode));
```

See towards the bottom of the [Extended Class Example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_example.htm) documentation for more information.

Comment: Thanks Keith.           After That I got another error "Line No 31: Variable does not exist: parent" error is shown.

Comment: String jsonPayload = JSON.serialize(parent);

Comment: @preeth The immediate problem is that the parent object is not in scope when you try to serialize it. But there is a parent object for every loan__Loan_Account__c; you could add those to an array (declared before the loan__Loan_Account__c loop to it is still in scope after the loop) and serialize the array. But that is a design decision for you.

Comment: I want to execute the 3 classes. way this is correct.                                      1. Deliquientdays   s = new  Deliquientdays (); 
String sch = '0 0 * * * ?';
System.schedule('Deliquientdays', sch, s);

2. Deliquientdays   s = new  Deliquientdays ();
database.executeBatch(s,200);                                                                           If  I am using the second one i got a error like that "Line: 10, Column: 1
Argument must be an object that implements Database.Batchable"

Comment: I am not using the batch class.

Comment: I want to schedule the class and I want to debug the JSON format

Comment: @preeth If you have a new question create a new question; you can link back to this one for context.